# Issue with AT+CUSD command

Tags: at-command

I want to check balance of sim card via AT command . Everything is running fine.
But i am not able to enter in menu of response. When i am trying to enter in it Its giving me "invalid request" error from operator. While in mobile phone its working fine.

```
Checking Selected Port COM11 
Data Received - AT+CNMI=1,1
AT
OK

OK

Data Received - AT+CUSD=1,*121#
OK

Data Received - 
+CUSD: 2,"My Airtel App:Track your daily data usage, balance, validity and 
Recharge online. Download now from Play Store/ App Store",15

Data Received - 
+CUSD: 1,"919771272794
1 Change Language
2 Balance
3 New Offers
4 My Offer
5 My Account Info
6 Coupon Recharge
7 Other Services
8 DTH
9 Payments Bank
",15

Data Received - > AT+CUSD=1,2

OK

Data Received - 
+CUSD: 1,"Invalid request.
1 Change Language
2 Balance
3 New Offers
4 My Offer
5 My Account Info
6 Coupon Recharge
7 Other Services
8 DTH
9 Payments Bank
",15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use
**

```
AT+CSCS="GSM"
AT+CUSD=1,"*121#",15
```

**

And you'll get the following message (as usual)

```
*CUSD: 1,"My Airtel App:Track your daily data usage, balance, validity and 
Recharge online. Download now from Play Store/ App Store",15

Data Received - 
+CUSD: 1,"919771272794
1 Change Language
2 Balance
3 New Offers
4 My Offer
5 My Account Info
6 Coupon Recharge
7 Other Services
8 DTH
9 Payments Bank
",15*
```

Now

```
AT+CUSD=1,"n",15
```

n is your choice number.
eg: 
to get the balance you will enter

```
AT+CUSD=1,"2",15
```

I had the same problem.